# How to volunteer for arduino projects?

Tags: programming

I have master in electronics and IT. I know various microcontrollers programming in `c`. I want to volunteer myself to learn for arduino Projects especially for low Level Drivers etc. Can somebody suggest me Websites or way ?

Comment: You want to do what? Help other people, or get help from other people? It's unclear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Arduino paradigm is based on abstracting the hardware to a few simple function calls.  So many drivers appear simple to the end user (end programmer).

Most go [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Libraries) for a list of libraries (which have already been written) and how to use them.  I believe these libraries are distributed with the Arduino SDK.  To learn more about writing libraries go [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial). I am not aware of any formal method of submitting Arduino libraries.  If I wanted to find out more I would go [here](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/board,53.0.html) and participate in the forum.  However, using the forums search, I found [this](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=262051.0) specific (several years old) post where it says:

> You can add a page to the Playground section:
>   http://playground.arduino.cc/ You might start by adding your website
>   with Arduino code to the index of the playground, perhaps a page in
>   the Playground section is not needed. The index can contain links to
>   websites, to the Arduino forum or to a page in the Playground section.
>
> You can not change or add to the reference or official libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the libraries to read sensors like as Dallas/Maxim 1Wire products, or to interface to RF-, WiFi-, and other radios are user-contributed and maintained, and most, if not all, of them are community maintained and on github.

Update:

> Is there any official repository for arduino libraries where someone
>   can contribute and submit patches?

"Official": I don't think so, at least I don't know of one if there is, but I am also just learning my way around the open sources.

But you'll probably find most of the libraries in github, and they are usually there to share development. They aren't generally grouped as "Arduino", but by each author's github username.

So the best approach is probably to identify the library in your "libraries" folder that you want to update, and its author's name which is usually in the source-code header comments. And, if you get lucky, a URL to the github project. Otherwise go to github and search for the library, using the author's name or a quick comparison of some the source code to be sure you've really found the same library.

(As I am a user & beneficiary of open source code, you have my sincere thanks for choosing to do this! I haven't gotten that far yet; I hope to, soon.)

Comment: can I contribute ? Is there any official repository for arduino libraries where someone can contribute and submit patches?